# How to get child of json in react native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I need to get src from json file.

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 38,
    "name": "Product",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 26,
            "src": "https://example.com/image.png",
            "name": "pants",
            "alt": ""
        }
    ],
    ...
```

Codes:

```
<ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData)=>
          <View style={{height:40}}>
            <Text>{rowData.images}</Text>
          </View>
        }
        />
```

I can show id or name by rowData.name, but images src not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [datatype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) residing in the `images` key is an array, I think grabbing an index from the array would help you do what you're looking for.

Could you try `rowData.images[0]`? The subsequent code I'd add depends on whether or not you expect there to be multiple images, and what you want to do with the images.

If you want to display the image you're gonna need to use the [React Native Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) component.

```
<View style={{height:40}}>
  <Image
    style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
    source={{ uri: dataRow.images[0].src }}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: This will not work if there's more than one image and if there's only one image you shouldn't be using an array.

Comment: @swonder correct, the question could be asked better but Alireza is a new member so I was just trying to get him going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the array of images to access the `src` property.

You can achieve that like this (untested):

```
<ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={ (rowData)=> {
         return rowData.images.map( (image, index) => {
            return (<View key={index}><Text> { image.src } </Text></View>)
          })
        }}
/>
```

Comment: Try adding a return, so `return rowData.images.map...`

Comment: worked but we have a warning: each child in an array should have a unique key props.

Comment: Easily fixale, in the return statement on the `<View>` add `<View key={index}>` then change the map to `images.map( ( image, index ) => ` and your problem should be solved.